TypeScript missing properties when declaring an array
Fairly new to Typescript and Im getting this error about missing properties when delcaring an array of string.
Any help would really be appreciated.


Can you please share your whole method in your question?

I guess you missed () at the end. Please use below line to get persons:
const persons:any[] = await sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Persons").items.select("PersonName","Id").orderBy("PersonName", true)();


Tried that and now get Type 'Promise<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 16 more

Can you please share the whole method in your question?
